How can I let users choose their own role?
On Drupal 11 I want that when a user registers (creates an account), they can choose between the authorized roles.
For example, I have the role author, creator, moderator.
I want them to have the choice between the role author and creator.
How can I let users choose their own role?

Drupal core's role selection does not have permissions, so you will need to add custom code or use a contrib module to allow users to select their own roles.
There are several modules in this space:

Registration Role
Multiple Registration
Select Registration Roles


Thanks but none of these modules are compatible with Drupal 11

Registration Role is compatible with Drupal 11 in the dev branch; support was added in this issue: https://www.drupal.org/project/registration_role/issues/3470959
